# TextBox.Text property not being set when I set it?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the weirdest thing as it works for me in some code in not other.  The following code is in a class that subclasses TextBox (NOTE: I don't know if it matters but I subclass the Text property to set/get from a private field _realText)

In the below code, the first base.Text = this.RealText works fine!!!  We also set it inside that method MaskData() as well and it works!!!!  so why in the world does it not work in the if(!field.isSecure) section?  (look at the logs for what I mean).  I tried adding Invalidate(), Update() after base.Text=temp but that didn't help.

Code:

```
    private void SetupTextInBox()
    {
        if (isInManualMode)
        {
            this.ReadOnly = false;
            base.Text = this.RealText;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ReadOnly = true;
            if (!field.IsSecure)
            {
                string temp = this.RealText;
                log.Info("This field is not secure so show it. field=" + field.Variable + " real='" + temp+"'");
                base.Text = temp;
                log.Info("text value='" + base.Text+"'");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MaskData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Logs

```
2012-06-30 07:15:51,468 [1] INFO  AlpineAccess.Plugins.SecureTalkPlugin.SecureTextControl (null) - This field is not secure so show it. field=1.acc real='2222' 
2012-06-30 07:15:51,468 [1] INFO  AlpineAccess.Plugins.SecureTalkPlugin.SecureTextControl (null) - text value=''
```

EDIT: Note that this method is ALWAYS called from the same thread.  It comes from server notifications telling us a tone on a phone somewhere else has been pressed, AND then that thread calls a BeginInvoke to put it in the GUI/controls thread or whatnot.

code just upstream from the above method is

```
    public void AppendDTMFDigit(string digit)
    {
        log.Info("specified="+field.MaxSpecified+" someone appending dtmf digit on field=" + field.Variable+" fieldMax="+field.Max+" len="+RealText.Length);
        if (field.MaxSpecified && this.RealText.Length >= field.Max)
            return; //shortcut out since we can't exceed max digits

        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            this.RealText = this.RealText + digit;
            log.Info("new realtext=" + this.RealText);
            SetupTextInBox();
        }
        )); 
    }
```

MORE INFO: If I change ALL my client code to stop using Text property and use RealText property, and then stop overriding the Text property, it then works fine.  (Obviously I don't want that though as now I can't just change from my control to TextBox and back easily without changing lots of client code referring to the RealText property....ugh, may have to live with that though....seems like some kind of odd bug.

MORE INFO: got debugger stepping into it and this is very odd.

2 very odd things.

1. It steps into the getter, not the setter???
2. It steps into MY Text property instead of TextBox's Text Property.

grrrrr, why would that be...sounds like a major bug, right? I mean, base.Text should refer to superclass's base, correct? – Dean Hiller just now edit

Adding Text method property code

```
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return RealText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Not allowed to set RealText to null.  Set to empty string instead");
            RealText = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What;s the value of 'temp'? Is this.RealText a property? If so is that property correctly reading the private backing field? Is the backing field set? Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: sorry, my log should have said temp instead of real but from the logs you can see the value of temp is '2222' from the first log statement.

Comment: Have you debugged? I'm sure your setter is being run - any chance you can stick a breakpoint on it? Just step into the setter (usually this is set to auto-step-over, but you can turn it off in the debugger settings)

Comment: I did try stepping into it but it said something about skipping over.  How do I turn that off in debugger settings(Visual Studio 2010) so I can try that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388.aspx

Comment: 2 very odd things.  1. It steps into the getter, not the setter???  2. It steps into MY Text property instead of TextBox's Text Property.  grrrrr, why would that be...sounds like a major bug, right?  I mean, base.Text should refer to superclass's base, correct?

Comment: @DeanHiller Can You explain this: "I don't know if it matters but I subclass the Text property to set/get from a private field _realText"?

Comment: okay, did that and pasted the very bizarre results to the end of my post.

Comment: Can you post the property code for RealText - I assume RealText is in the same class as the overridden Text property?

Comment: @Grzegorz pasted that code to bottom of post.

Comment: shouldn't base.Text step into TextBox.Text "Setter" property though!!!!  This really just seems like some big bug here.

Comment: @DeanHiller TextBox has a `TextChanged` Event inherited from Control. I belive that it "gets" the value inside Setter to populate the event args. Nothing scary there :)

Comment: but my main point is when I step into base.Text = temp; the debugger steps into a "GETTER" not a "SETTER" method.  how is that possible since I am setting Text property??  Also, it steps into MY Text propery and not the base class Text property for some reason.

Comment: full source posted as one of the answers now as I give up....going with workaround but will check back as I am curious if anyone has the same issue with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full source for this user control that doesn't work unless you comment out the Text property is here (You would have to use a RealText property and expose that one to clients instead because base.Text does not appear to work properly).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using log4net;
using IntraNext.Win32.Config;

namespace AlpineAccess.Plugins.SecureTalkPlugin
{

    public partial class SecureTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SecureTextControl));

        private static readonly Color COLOR_FOCUSED = Color.Yellow;
        private static readonly Color COLOR_FOCUSED_MANUALMODE = Color.PaleGreen;

        private FocusEvent focusListener;
        private Field field;
        private bool isInManualMode;
        private EventHandler textChanged;
        private string RealText;

        public SecureTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RealText = "";
        }

        internal void Initialize(Field field, FocusEvent focusList, EventHandler textChanged)
        {
            this.focusListener = focusList;
            this.textChanged = textChanged;
            this.field = field;

            this.Enter += new EventHandler(SecureTextBox_Enter);
            this.Leave += new EventHandler(SecureTextBox_Leave);
            this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(SecureTextBox_TextChanged);

            MenuItem mnuItemNew = new MenuItem();
            mnuItemNew.Text = "&Clear";

            //THIS textbox HAS a context menu ALREADY BUT here we assign a new context menu to
            //our text box to replace the old one which had cut, paste etc. that we don't want
            //the agent using...
            this.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            this.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(mnuItemNew);

            mnuItemNew.Click += new EventHandler(clear_Click);

            SwitchModes();
        }

        void SecureTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(isInManualMode) //make sure if in manual mode, we keep changes up to date in realText field
                RealText = Text;
            textChanged(sender, e);
        }

        void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearAll();
        }

        internal void SetManualMode(bool inManual)
        {
            if (isInManualMode == inManual)
                return; //we don't care if there is no change so return;

            isInManualMode = inManual;
            SwitchModes();
        }

        void SecureTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log.Info("exiting=" + field.Variable);
            focusListener(field.Variable, false, this.RealText);
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                ChangeBackground();
            }
            ));            
        }

        void SecureTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log.Info("entering=" + field.Variable );
            focusListener(field.Variable, true, this.RealText);
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                ChangeBackground();
            }
            ));
        }

        private void SwitchModes()
        {
            SetupTextInBox();
            ChangeBackground();
        }

        private void SetupTextInBox()
        {
            if (isInManualMode)
            {
                this.ReadOnly = false;
                base.Text = RealText;
            }
            else if (!field.IsSecure)
            {
                this.ReadOnly = true;
                string temp = RealText;
                base.Text = temp;
                Invalidate();
                log.Info("txt=" + base.Text + " temp=" + temp);
            }
            else //not manual mode and IsSecure so mask it and make it readonly
            {
                this.ReadOnly = true;
                MaskData();
            }
        }

        private void MaskData()
        {
            log.Debug("mask=" + this.field.NumBeginDigitsToMaskSpecified + " num=" + field.NumBeginDigitsToMask + " txtLen=" + RealText.Length);
            int numDigitsToMask = RealText.Length;
            if (this.field.NumBeginDigitsToMaskSpecified && this.field.NumBeginDigitsToMask < RealText.Length)
            {
                int numDigits = this.field.NumBeginDigitsToMask;
                string maskedPart = "".PadLeft(numDigits, '●');
                string unmasked = RealText.Substring(numDigits);
                string full = maskedPart + unmasked;
                base.Text = full;
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug("masking all digits");
                base.Text = "".PadLeft(RealText.Length, '●');
            }
        }

        private void ChangeBackground()
        {
            if (isInManualMode)
                SetManualModeColor();
            else
                SetNonManualModeColor();
        }

        private void SetNonManualModeColor()
        {
            if (this.Focused)
                this.BackColor = COLOR_FOCUSED;
            else
                this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        }

        private void SetManualModeColor()
        {
            if (this.Focused)
                this.BackColor = COLOR_FOCUSED_MANUALMODE;
            else
                this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        }

        public void AppendDTMFDigit(string digit)
        {
            log.Info("manualmode="+isInManualMode+" specified=" + field.MaxSpecified + " someone appending dtmf digit on field=" + field.Variable + " fieldMax=" + field.Max + " len=" + RealText.Length);

            if (isInManualMode)
                return;
            else if (field.MaxSpecified && RealText.Length >= field.Max)
                return; //shortcut out since we can't exceed max digits

            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                RealText = RealText + digit;
                SetupTextInBox();
            }
            )); 
        }

        internal void ClearAll()
        {
            log.Info("Cleared textbox for =" + field.Variable);
            base.Text = "";
            RealText = "";
            SetError("");
        }

        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return RealText;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Not allowed to set RealText to null.  Set to empty string instead");
                RealText = value;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set to "" to clear the error or set anything to make valid
         */
        public void SetError(string error)
        {
            if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
                return;

            SecureTextBox box = this;
            //set to "" to clear the error
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(box, error);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably stepping into a getter because it's getting the value of the other property that it's assigning and also you don't have the source for Textbox.Text so it probably won't step in to the setter. Also what's a little confusing is naming properties the same as fields - generally private fields use a prefix so that you can distinguish them in code (e.g. _realText instead of RealText) - I'm having a look now

Comment: uhm, temp is a "local" variable so that does not make sense.  It steps into Text property getter on base.Text = temp in the code above

Comment: Have you checked my answer - it might be linked to that (without your project debugging is difficult), regardless of this there is still the overridden text issue

Comment: oh, and yes, I should do _realText(I mostly live in java world so getting used to it)

Comment: I checked your answer, but basically never got the override to Text to work(as base.Text would step into the wrong thing then which was just so weird)

Comment: ie. finally gave up and exposed RealText instead

Answer (score 1):

Ok you've overridden Text - and you have THIS on one of your lines:

```
RealText = Text;
```

This will call the most derived 'Text' property (since you didn't specify base) and will call your overridden 'Text' on the current control

Which means you are setting RealText to itself

e.g.

```
 void SecureTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (isInManualMode) //make sure if in manual mode, we keep changes up to date in realText field
     RealText = Text; <---- **THIS CALLS THE OVERIDDEN 'Text' BELOW**

     ... snip
```

calls

```
public override string Text 
{
    get { return RealText; }
}
```

Which is a bit...nuts!

Did you mean to do:

```
 void SecureTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (isInManualMode) //make sure if in manual mode, we keep changes up to date in realText field
     RealText = base.Text; <--- THIS?
```

Check your code carefully, I bet this is one of your issues

Also it might be useful to change your naming conventions a little... e.g. I tend to use an underscore for private/protected fields

```
private string _realText;
```

instead of caps which is for properties

```
private string RealText;
```

Don't usually expose public fields, usually use properties but when I do I tend to use the same casing as I do for properties

This is so that it's easier to differentiate between properties and fields in your code and makes debugging a bit easier

Comment: good catch, but I am not in manual mode when running the test.  I am in secure mode so it never hits that line(though I will fix that).  I finally just exposed RealText instead, and commented out my Text property override and it worked with no other changes.

Comment: Glad you sorted it, sometimes these kind of errors can eat days of time!